# How do you remove a bookmark in Daum PotPlayer

Tags: daum-pot-player

I seem to be able to add bookmarks in PotPlayer, but I can't seem to remove them.

I press the 'H' key to bring up the bookmark menu, and there's the option of 'Clear bookmarks of the related item' ie delete all the bookmarks in the file.

But is there a way to remove individual bookmarks?

Comment: It also annoyingly removes bookmarks from the wrong file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go to bookmark menu, by typing `h` keyboerd button , then choose '`Edit bookmarks`' 
, a menu will be opened where you can see all your bookmarks, you can then select and delete the one you want : [image]
[image]